# How to implement Artifactory for multiple products

Tags: continuous-integration, artifactory, continuous-deployment

We are in the process of implementing CI-CD pipeline and after doing some research zeroed on Artifactory for storing binaries.
We have 4 products, now shall we deploy 4 instances of artifactory or single instance shared by all 4 products ? All products are independent of each other.

What is the best way in above scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

A single Artifactory can manage all of your products. The reason for deploying more than one Artifactory instance should be, load or geolocation. In case that you don't have high load and that all of your developers are located on the same site, I don't see a reason for deploying 4 instances. 
Which type of Artifactory are you planning to use? (OSS / Pro)

Comment: Thanks Ariel. Presently, we are planning to use OSS version. My thought process behind 4 instances was clear separation of products & load (due to CI, artifactory might become overloaded) - If artifactory can help in clear separation & manage load then we don't need 4 instances. I think load is not a issue for OSS version also. Can you please suggest for best way of managing clear separation of repositories of all products ? HA can be become tricky issue with OSS - we can later consider moving to Pro after sufficient experience.

Comment: The clear separation can be done in a way that each product will use different repository and each team will only have permissions on that repository using permission target.